# HttpResponseMessage Content is always an empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a generic post method in a base class in my MVC API client application:

```
    protected async Task<T> PerformPostAsync<T>(string requestUri, HttpContent c)
    {
        _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
        _webApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var webApiResponse = await _webApiClient.PostAsync(requestUri, c);
        var responseContent = webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
```

I am calling the above method to Post an object:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddEmployee(EmployeeImport employee)
    {
        var param = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);
        HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(param, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await PerformPostAsync<HttpResponseMessage>("entity/NewEmployee", contentPost);
        return response;
    }
```

In my Web API method, `public async Task <IActionResult> CreateEmployee([FromBody]EmployeeImport Employee)`, if it is successful, I have `return Ok();`

In the PerformPostAysnc method, if I hover over `var webApiResponse`, it shows as `Status: OK` but when I call this line:

```
var responseContent = webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

`responseContent` is ALWAYS an empty string, so the response in my AddEmployee method is always null:

```
var response = await PerformPostAsync<HttpResponseMessage>("entity/NewEmployee", contentPost);
```

Also, if I force it to throw an error it shows the error:
[image]

Then when it gets to the call that initiated the Post, response shows a StatusCode of OK:

[image]
I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the OK response by changing my API method from returning `<IActionResult>` to returning `<HttpResponseMessage>` so I do receive the success message now.

```
 public async Task <HttpResponseMessage> CreateEmployee([FromBody]EmployeeImport Employee)

        if(success)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        }
```